# Mysql select into statement in a more understandable format

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I m using MYSQL procedures a lot and always like to uses the following insert format:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE SET a = AA,
                      b = BB ;
```

over

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (a,b) VALUES (AA, BB);
```

Since it is just more simple to read when working with many variables

however, when i try to use the following syntax

```
SELECT a = AA,
       b = BB 
FROM TABLE;
```

over

```
SELECT AA, BB INTO a, b FROM TABLE;
```

The syntax is not working, 
Is there a simpler way to write a INSERT INTO query , similar to the insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the second form for `insert`s.  The `insert`/`set` is specific only to MySQL.  You might prefer this, however:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(a,b)
    SELECT AA as a, BB as b;
```

As for your question, when you write:

```
SELECT a = AA,
       b = BB 
FROM TABLE;
```

You are creating two boolean expressions that, if parsed correctly, would return 0, 1, or NULL.  If your intention is to assign values to variables, then you need to use `:=`:

```
SELECT a := AA,
       b := BB 
FROM TABLE;
```

If your intention is to rename the columns, then use `as`:

```
SELECT AA as a, BB as b
FROM TABLE;
```

EDIT:

I think this should work:

```
SELECT @a := AA,
       @b := BB 
FROM TABLE;
```

I don't think you need the `declare`.  If you want to do the assignment *and* return nothing, this might work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @a := AA,
             @b := BB 
      FROM TABLE
     ) t
WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I tried it, and it worked, but only after the following modifications.
DECLAREa tinyint(1);
SELECT @a:=columnA  from tableA limit 1;
SELECT @a;
however,  this does create a different problem for me ,
the assignment of value to a variable now also returns a resultset , which was not my intent and I would like to avoid it if that is possible , thanks for any reply.